# Http Post Array in Ionic 3 - Angular 4 - Sqlite

Tags: angular, sqlite, typescript, ionic3

I'm trying to post array of contactos on a WebService.

When send the array this data appears in NULL in WebService.

I'm confused with Let params{}

The error is object undefinded.

And the method POST doesn´t works.

I'm using Ionic3 - Angular4 and Sqlite.

This is my home.ts

```
public contactos: any [] = [];

constructor(public navCtrl: NavController,
    private sqlite: SQLite,
    private toast: Toast,
    public http: Http) {
    }
        postRequest(){
                this.sqlite.create({
                name: 'ionicdb.db',
                location: 'default'
            }).then((db: SQLiteObject) =>{
              db.executeSql('SELECT * FROM Contactos ORDER BY rowid DESC', {})
              .then(result =>  {
                this.contactos = [];
                for(var i=0; i<result.rows.length; i++) {
                  this.contactos.push({
                    rowid:result.rows.item(i).rowid,
                    nombre:result.rows.item(i).nombre,
                    telefono:result.rows.item(i).telefono,
                    ext:result.rows.item(i).ext,
                    correo:result.rows.item(i).correo,
                    empresa:result.rows.item(i).empresa})  

                    var headers = new Headers();
                    headers.append("Accept", 'application/json');
                    headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
                    let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });
                    let params = { 
                      nombre: 'Sergio',
                      telefono: '1234567',
                      ext: '000',
                      correo: 'zergiodkamargo.sc@gmail.com',
                      empresa: 'Globaltek'
                }

                 this.http.post("http://181.48.244.108/FeriaDutotec/api/Contactos1", JSON.stringify(params), options)
                .subscribe(contactos => {
                this.contactos.push(contactos.json())
                console.log(contactos ['_body']);
                this.toast.show('Datos Sincronizados!' , '4000', 'center').subscribe(
                  toast => {
                    console.log(contactos);
                  }
                )
                }, error => {
                console.log(error.message);// Error obteniendo los datos!
                this.toast.show('Error en la sincronizacion!'+ error.message, '4000' , 'center').subscribe(
                  toast => {
                    console.log(toast);
                  }
                  )
                  }); 
    }  
        console.log('Result')
        })
        .catch(e => console.log(e));
        console.log('Create')
        }) 
        .catch(e => console.log(e));
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

please replace this line

```
this.http.post("http://181.48.244.108/FeriaDutotec/api/Contactos1", JSON.stringify(this.contactos), options)
```

Comment: I try, but appears this: {"id":115,"nombre":null,"telefono":null,"ext":null,"correo":null,"empresa":null} and the array is empty.  :/